# Why doesn't Visual Studio 2008 permanently show Class Name column in Test Results window?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

Using the Show/Remove Columns context menu option in the Test Results window I can show the Class Name column. However, when I then close and reopen Visual Studio 2008 the Class Name column is not longer there.

How do I permanently display the Class Name column?

EDIT: I started this edit thinking I'd found the reliable way to reproduce the problem but it turns out not the case. All I can say is since reporting the error the problem has not occurred until tonight.

On this occasion I open used Ctrl+T to effectively run Test > Debug > Tests in Current Context. This time the Class Name column was not there. Close VS, reopen and run all tests, Class Name column still missing. Reshow the column close VS and now it appears for all test runs. Go figure.

Comment: I've actually tried your scenario and the class name will appear as soon as the unit tests are ran (after restarting VS). Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I would have posted a reply to Dan's comment if I could.  If you rerun your unit tests after restarting Visual Studio, your class name column will reappear.  I just tested this and it works, at least on VS2008 SP1.

Comment: Typical isn't it. Of course today its working as expected but I assure you it wasn't. I'll keep an eye on it for a few days before accepting your answer.